# Highest Number of Occurrences without using Limit

Tags: sql, sqlite

I searched this topic a lot and I have it working so it gets THE highest number of occurrences, but I want to make the SQL grab an arbitrary amount (in case there are multiple values with the highest amount). 
Right now I have:

```
SELECT houses.cars, COUNT(houses.cars) as Numb 
FROM houses 
Group By houses.cars Order By Numb Desc 
Limit 1;
```

which returns THE highest number of occurrences, but for example if there are 2 types of cars with 8 occurrences I want it to return both of them.

I know this is how you do it when you want the highest values when they're durations (integers):

```
SELECT times.duration AS 'Hour', 
FROM times 
WHERE times.duration >= (SELECT MAX(times.duration) 
                         FROM times);
```

but anytime I try to do similar logic with COUNT it gives syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

To keep ties you can use the `having` clause with a subquery:

**Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ce7ec/6/0

```
select cars,
       count(*)
  from houses
 group by cars
having count(*) = (select max(num_occur)
                     from (select cars,
                                  count(*) as num_occur
                             from houses
                            group by cars))
```

If you were using Oracle or SQL Server you could do this without the subquery:

Such a solution using Oracle 12c:

```
select cars,
       count(*)
  from houses
 group by cars
 order by 2 desc
 fetch first 1 rows with ties;
```

Such a solution using SQL Server:

```
select top(1) with ties
       cars,
       count(*)
  from houses
 group by cars
 order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do without using sub query ?

Comment: @Amee not with sqllite. In other databases, such as Oracle and SQL Server you have the `with ties` option, which would allow you to do this without a subquery.